# Create financial report with SQL

Tags: sql

I want to create a financial report using a select statement for example: my start month is april 2000 and the end month is march 2001 how can I do that?

```
SELECT  monthList.MonthName ,transcation.id,transaction.amount(
SELECT 10 ordby, 'January' MonthName 
UNION SELECT 11, 'February' 
UNION SELECT 12, 'March'
UNION SELECT 1, 'April' 
UNION SELECT 2,'May'
UNION SELECT 3,'June'
UNION SELECT 4,'July' 
UNION SELECT 5,'August' 
UNION SELECT 6,'September'
UNION SELECT 7,'October' 
UNION SELECT 8,'November' 
UNION SELECT 9,'December') monthList 
left  JOIN (select YEAR(Date) [Year], MONTH(Date) [Month],DATENAME(MONTH,Date) [Month Name],sum(Amount)as amount 
FROM transaction 
where id=2 GROUP BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date),DATENAME(MONTH, Date) ) as t on t.[Month Name]=monthList.[Month Name])
```

Comment: Perhaps `UNION ALL` instead.

Comment: Please show a schema, sample data, expected result, and current result. It's not really clear what you're asking here...